# Paralells Confixx Redirect with no htaccess file to Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, indexing, parallels

I use shared hosting and have previously had a dreamweaver site on my domain. It is all managed on Confixx. I've installed wordpress via software on the Confixx and it set itself up inside of the html file.

I would like to have the wordpress site as my main page and get rid of the old site altogether but I am nervous about what I can keep or delete in the site.

I'd also be happy to just redirect directly to Wordpress in the directory but it seems that has no effect when I do this via their domains tab.

I can't create an htaccess file to do this either.

What's my best way forward? What is safe to delete in the root folder and what must be kept?

Would be really grateful to hear any suggestions and get some help on this!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could backup the old index.php and replace it with the following content:

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location:http://www.your.new/domain");
    exit;
?>
```